# RegEx: Optional not working

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex. I found a solution for my following problem, but I want to know why my first snippet is not working:

Assume I want to match with (Python) regex `c`,`[a]c` or `[b]c` (this is MWE, in reality a,b,c represent more complex patterns).

I figured out:

**Not working snip:**

```
^(\[(a)?|(b)?\])?c$
```

This is matching `c`, but it is **not** matching `[a]c` or `[b]c`

If I remove the outer optional group so `\[(a)?|(b)?\]c$`, it matches `[a]z` and `[b]z` but understandable not `c`

I can fix this by going for:

**Working snip:**

`^(\[a\])|(\[b\])?c$`

**Can someone explain me why this latest is working and the first one is not?**

Comment: The "working" one also matches other stuff, for example `re.search(r'^(\[a\])|(\[b\])?c$', '[a]junkhere')` and `re.search(r'^(\[a\])|(\[b\])?c$', 'junkherec')`. Is that ok?

Comment: Robert, please clarify if `[]c` is an expected match. If not, you actually do not want to make `a` and `b` optional, and you will need something like [`^(\[(?:(a)|(b))\])?c$`](https://regex101.com/r/wINJTI/2).

Comment: @StefanPochmann Your regex - `r'^(\[a\])|(\[b\])?c$'` - suffers the same issue as OP's, the `^` only applies to the `(\[a\])` alternative, while `$` only applies to `(\[b\])?c` alternative. Grouping will make it work: `^(?:(\[a\])|(\[b\])?c)$`

Comment: OK, I modified my answer as per the comment above.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Huh? "My" regex? It's not mine, it's robert's. And its issue you point out is exactly its issue that **I** point out.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well, I see you commented the "working snippet" pattern. I only dwelled upon the "non-working" one. It is true that they both do not work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have [**grouped**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the `a` and `b` alternatives:

```
^(\[(?:(a)|(b))\])?c$
    ^^^       ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wINJTI/2). If you do not do it, the `[` is only matched before `a`, and `]` is only matched after `b`. And your regex matches `[ac`, `b]c`, `]c`, `[c` strings, see [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5kcfmP/2) and the diagram:

[image]

See the fixed regex details below:

- `^` - start of the string
- `(` - start of the first capturing group:

  - `\[` - a literal `[`
  - `(?:`  - start of a non-capturing group:

    - `(a)` - a capturing group matching `a`
    - `|` - or
    - `(b)` - a capturing group matching `b`
  - `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `\]` - a `]`
- `)?` - end of the first capturing group, and `?` makes it match 1 or 0 times
- `c` - a `c`
- `$` - end of string.

A fixed regex diagram:

[image]

P.S. These diagrams are generated at https://jex.im/regulex.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I understand your point. Still, the right *grouping* will be key to solving the main issue. I am not getting your "empty" regex bit, though. `c` is obligatory at any rate.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Because in the expected outputs, *`c`, `[a]c` or `[b]c`*, `c` is present in all expected output examples.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: 1) `a` and `b` are still optional since they are inside an optional group. 2) A non-capturing group is used so as not to change the order of the capturing groups (so as not to have to adjust the code for the modified pattern).

Comment: 1) So now you're going by robert's "not working" regex? Then I go by their "working" one, where `c` *isn't* obligatory. 2) Ah, ok. Though robert's own "working" one already has different capturing groups, so it doesn't look to me like that's important.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to match c, [a]c or [b]c then the you should use the expression below instead.

```
^((\[a\])?|(\[b\])?)?c$
```

Answer (score -1):

**Your first regex behavior:**

[image]

**Obviously, it has no valid path to represent [a]c.**